# React router 6 NavLink show active with trailing slash

Tags: react-router-dom

In React Router v6, I want a `<NavLink>` to show as active when the current route does or doesn't include a trailing slash. So the following should display as active when the route is `/foo`, or `/foo/`, but not `/foo/bar`. Is that possible?

```
<NavLink end to="/foo">
...
</NavLink>
```

Comment: I don't think so. Is the issue that `"/foo/"` ***doesn't*** get marked as active when the currently matched route path is `"/foo"`?

Comment: Yes, that's what happens

Comment: That's sort of by design. With the trailing `"/"` character there's a new path segment, `/""` and the path no longer ends with `"/foo"`.

Comment: Makes sense. In the migration guide in the docs, it mentions: "One other thing to notice is that all path matching in v6 ignores the trailing slash on the URL." I was hoping that this meant that the `NavLink` component respected that. Thanks.